# req.url always gives me "/" no matter what path I use

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

```
//Force HTTPS
if (app.get('env') == 'production'){
    app.use('*',function(req,res,next){
        if(req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']!='https') res.redirect(301, "https://" + req.host + req.url)
            /* x-forwarded-proto is used because heroku */
        else next()
    })
}
```

**Edit:** for anyone using this example -- `req.host` is deprecated, be sure to use `req.hostname` instead.

I have a block of code that redirects any http request to the same page, but with https protocol.. it works beautifully except that making an http request always redirects to the homepage. I've traced it down to the fact that `req.url` is always equal to `'/'` no matter what the request url actually is.

i.e. If I navigate to page `http://hostname.com/my/path` I would expect `req.url`on the server to equal `"my/path/"` but instead it just equals `"/"`.

I'm thinking this has something to do with either react-router, which I'm using for the front-end, or the way that heroku internally redirects the request, but I have not been able to find a solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mounting a function to a path with `app.use()` rewrites the `req.url` by removing the mount point part from it. You should use `req.originalUrl` instead or omit the path argument:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // req.url not changed as path is not specified
});

app.use('/foobar', function (req, res, next) {
  // foobar removed from the req.url
});

app.use('*', function (req, res, next) {
  // everything (*) removed from the req.url
  // original URL available in req.originalUrl
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly the clarification that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Is `app.use` express or something? My guess would be that youre probably performing a redirect before you get to that snippet of code you provided. It's probably not react-router because front-end stuff happens after the backend returns a response (meaning req.url shouldnt be affected by react-router because react-router comes later)

Comment: Yes, `app.use()` is express.. That's a good point about react-router. I've put this snippet before everything except the modues/db connection/ etc.. so it's definitely not being redirected prior